# Workload/Capacity of a Practitioner in FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir

Would like to know if there are any existing FHIR resource that can be used to update and maintain the workload/capacity of a particular Practitioner/Device. These values are to be updated periodically based on some business logic.

Regards,
Harsha

Answer (score 0):

It sort of depends on what's meant by "workload".  You could query the number of appointment Slot instances associated with the Practitioner that are 'open'.  You could also capture Observations that evaluate workload/capacity based on other considerations.  Each Observation would be a point-in-time assessment.  Beyond that, you'd probably be looking at using extensions.